# VS Code not found even though the terminal displays its version

Tags: macos, shell, visual-studio-code, installation, terminal

I downloaded VS Code CLI for Apple Silicon from the [website](https://code.visualstudio.com), and added the unzipped file `code` to `/usr/local/bin`. Now, `code --version` outputs

```
code-cli 1.78.2 (commit b3e4e68a0bc097f0ae7907b217c1119af9e03435)
```

whereas `code` outputs

```
[2023-05-20 05:40:00] info Searching for installations on your machine, this is done once and 
will take about 10 seconds...
No installation of Visual Studio Code Stable was found.
Download and unzip it from https://code.visualstudio.com and try again.

If you already installed Visual Studio Code and we didn't detect it, run 
`code version use stable --install-dir /path/to/installation`
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CLI `code` command will launch the GUI editor. It is not a command line editor. It is just a tool that looks for and launches the GUI editor.

The 'VS Code CLI' install is not a complete instance (-- which doesn't seem to be made clear in the [installation directions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac)).

1. Download the normal full `Visual Studio Code` for macOS.
2. Move the unzipped file to `/Applications`.
3. Launch 'Visual Studio Code' from `/Applications`.
4. From the command palette run the `Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH` command.

This command will create a symbolic link named `code` in `/usr/local/bin` that links to `/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code`. 'Applications' on macOS are folders with a `.app` extension. The `code` tool is self-contained within the `Visual Studio Code.app` folder.